# jQuery: Email validation with the 'name_lastName@company.com' format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

**Hello everyone:**

I'm trying to validate an email using jQuery using the following format:

> **[name]_[lastname] @ company.com** (always ending in 'company.com')

Here is a code sample:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <form onSubmit='validate(); return false;'>
  <p>Enter an email address:</p>
  <input id='email'>
  <button type='submit' id='validate'>Validate!</button>
  </form>

  <br/>
  <h2 id='result'></h2>
<script>
```

**CSS:**

```
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
```

**JS:**

```
function validateEmail(email) { 

    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(usmp.pe)$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

function validate(){
  $("#result").text("");
  var email = $("#email").val();
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#result").text(email + " is valid :)");
    $("#result").css("color", "green");
  } else {
    $("#result").text(email + " is not valid :(");
    $("#result").css("color", "red");
  }
  return false;
}

$("form").bind("submit", validate);
```

**I'm using the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardosfs/87gmt094/3/)**

With this sample I can validate emails ending in "company.com" but I can't figure it out how to validate emails with a "_" sign before the "@" between the name and last name. Any idea?

**Thank you!**

Comment: GOOGLE stuff http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: If you would be specific with the answer, instead to say "Google it" would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Well thats what I have attached a very specific link that you can read through. Doesnt matter if you read it here or on that webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a dash in after your first name regular expression, and copy it again for the last name.

It should look like this:

```
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))_(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(company.com)$/;
```

If you replace your code with this line, it should work.

(Edit: Changed the dash to an underscore)

Comment: Okay, I've tried using this and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Great!  Chan you click the check to say that this is the right answer?

Comment: Done. Thanks again for the answer! Straight to the point instead of sharing links.